# React; Axios; Getting Error 404 after requesting; The url is exactly the same as the endpoint url

Tags: reactjs, proxy, get, http-status-code-404, axios

I apologize for an inconsistencies with this post as it is my first. Please feel to give me tips on to how to better ask questions and what I should include and what I should leave out!

I really do not understand why I am getting an error 404. I have made plenty of projects that use axios and node in the way I am using it. I have checked against older projects and I do not see the difference.

This is the function that is making the request.

```
handleSearch() {
    const tempCSR = [];
    return axios
      .get("/api/search", this.state.tempSearchText)
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        tempCSR.push(response.data);
      })
      .catch(error => {});
    updateCSR(tempCSR);
  }
```

(It is a simple search function in my search component) 
Basically after typing in my input for the search I click search which fire this function.

My endpoint here:

```
app.get("http://localhost:3005/api/search", ic.search);
```

I have tried naming them the same, 
I have a proxy that states to use "http://localhost:3005" in the package.json, 
I have tried requiring axios in my server.js in my server folder, 
I have imported axios in all of my front end.

I only get GET http://localhost:3000/api/search 404 (Not Found) in my console (or 3005 when I type in the whole url in the axios request).

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error is in your app.get route, you are using the full url while you should only be using the location.

app.get("/api/search", ic.search);

Regards,
Rafael

Comment: This was basically the problem! I was calling the whole url and the proxy was also trying to call i guess which was giving me an error.

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure that in package.json "proxy": "http://yourapi.whatever" is well colocated? since axios.get() works this way you should double check that this line in your package.json is well written there.

it should look similar to the image: 
[image: package.json last line boilerplate]